# Github pages not finding html route

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a github pages set up with Jekyll (I build locally and only push `_site`) here: https://github.com/Eflores89/Eflores89.github.io

However, with 2 posts (the first and second), the site is not linking correctly to the post. If I test locally with `$ jekyll serve`, all the posts work correctly.

I'm wondering if it's the amount of tags or the special unicode characters in each tag (although the other posts have the same characters and similar amount of tags).

I've tried rebuilding several times locally and pushing. Any idea as to why these links are broken? Is there a max limit for tags (folders) for github pages work?

Comment: Can you explain how it is not linking correctly? It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further documentation, I figured this out: safe mode seems to not like building when the post is named with an ASCII character.

For example: `2015-12-01-A-típical post.md`will not build a folder and so the html route will not work. But `2015-12-01-A-tipical post.md` will build correctly as expected.